# How to display specific record after clicked on anchor tag using php?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I have two links, Delete and View. Delete is working perfectly. I am getting the issue on view link. I have to display specific records after clicked on view link.If you notice that delete anchor tag I wrote `href='delete.php?function=delete&del_id=$id'`. It's calling the delete.php file and deleting a specific record. I want to know about how to write in view anchor tag to display records? Please check below image.I want to clicked on view and display the records in text fields.PHP file added. Please check my ajax code. It is also not working. Ajax code is not working here. I have to display the output in the text field.If i write directly $id=2 then it is display records in alert. Hope you guys can understand now.Would you help me in this?

[image]

```
//delete.php
function view($conn) {
    $id=$_GET['view_id'];
    $admin_view="SELECT * from view_table WHERE Id=$id";
    $result = $conn->query($admin_view);
    if (isset($result->num_rows) > 0) {
         // output data of each row
        while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $parent_name=$row['Name'];
            $parent_email=$row['Email'];
            $admin_mobile=$row['Mobile_no'];  
        }
    }
}
```

```html
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
     <a href='delete.php?function=delete&del_id=$id' >Delete</a> 
     <a href='#Popup' onClick='a_onClick(<?php $id?>)' class='btn-view'>View</a>

             <form action="#" method="post">
                 <input type="text" name="Name" placeholder="username"  value="<?php echo $parent_name;?>" >
                 <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email"  value="<?php echo $parent_email;?>" >
                 <input type="text" name="Mobile_no" placeholder="Mobile no"  value="<?php echo $admin_mobile;?>" >

                 <a href="#" class="cancel">Cancel</a> <span class="close"></div>
             </form>

     <script>
         function a_onClick(id) {
var id = id;
var Name=$('#name').val();
             $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "delete.php?function=view&view_id=id",  
                 data:'Name='+Name,          
                 dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
                 success: function(response) {                    
                     // $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                     alert(response);
                 } 
             });
         }
     </script>
```

Comment: where is your php file content ?

Comment: first get data using ajax in success response set all get data in model then after show the model

Comment: show me your html table content and format

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Satish Sharma. Which table are u talking about?

Comment: Thanks for replying Sujal Patel. Can you help me with the code?

Comment: Can any one help me in this?

Comment: There seems to be quite a few errors or code missing. Starting at the beginning, when you hit view you call a Javascript function `a_onClick` where a variable `Name` is being used but it has not been defined anywhere. You need to define what Name is. Then you are also calling a variable $id that has not been defined either in the code shown. There is no reference to how you call the view that displays the initial table. Also, if the View (last block) is repeated for every row, you are creating the `a_onClick` and the `#Popup` many times.

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Marc Compte. Actually I am not good in Ajax.

Comment: did you find out the answer yet?
I would recomend first making it without ajax (so that you understand the whole process of what should go to the php script handeling the "show") and then modifying that code to use ajax. that way you are doing it in two smaller steps and it is a bit easier.
also your php code for deleting is prone to mysql injection. you should escape the parameters you get from $_GET or even better use prepared statements

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.flynorc, First i am trying in ajax only, From anchor tag it not passing the Id. If I type manually Id number Like var id=2 then it is displaying the output in alert popup.

Comment: Any one help me out in this?

Answer (score 0):

you need to change some changes

```
 <a href='#Popup' onClick='a_onClick(<?= $id ?>)' class='btn-view'>View</a>

<script>
         function a_onClick(id) {
              var id = id;

             $.ajax({    //create an ajax request to load_page.php
                 type: "GET",
                 url: "delete.php?function=view&view_id=id",  
                 data:'Name='+Name,          
                 dataType: "html", //expect html to be returned                
                 success: function(response) {                    
                     // $("#responsecontainer").html(response); 
                     alert(response);
                 } 
             });
         }
     </script>
```

hope its help you

Comment: Thanks for replying Mr.Ehsan, I tried your code but it is not working.